# MouseListener for JScrollBar arrow buttons

Tags: java, button, mouselistener, jscrollbar

http://s019.radikal.ru/i626/1203/ae/8420ef7757f7.png

```
    JScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("mouseClicked");
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("mousePressed");
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("mouseReleased");
        }
    });
```

It works if I click on the strip, but does not work when I click on the buttons

Comment: there I can9t see resons for why, for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Would listening for changes to the underlying model of the `JScrollBar` suit your needs?

Comment: I do not know, I need to define pressing these buttons, please give a working example

Comment: @user1221483 Pressing those buttons is already defined for you. When you press the button, the `JScrollPane` scrolls.

Comment: @user1221483 my curiosity, pleasy why MouseListener, all mouse events are correctly implemented in the API,

Answer (score 1):

The buttons are defined in the JScrollBar's UI so you need to extend the default UI implementation. Of course it is platform dependent. In my example I'll show you how to do it with `BasicScrollBarUI`.
You can define a custom JScrollBar by calling the `JScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBar(new CustomScrollBar());`
In your CustomScrollBar you can do the following:

```
public class CustomScrollBar extends JScrollBar {
    public CustomScrollBar() {
        setUI(new CustomUI());
    }
    class CustomUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {
        @Override
        protected void installListeners() {
            super.installListeners();
            if (incrButton != null) {
                incrButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        //Increment button is clicked!
                    }
                });
            }
            if (decrButton != null) {
                decrButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        //Decrement button is clicked!
                    }
               });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested it under XP but without a `JScrollPane`. 
I hope it helps!